# What is the appropriate logic to load delta values when using > and <=?

Tags: sql, etl

I am writing an ETL for initial full load and subsequent delta loads.

In the watermark table I am storing the table name, date. At each ETL run I load this value into variable (@last_run).

From the source table I select the max datetime value into a SQL variable (@current_max_date).

Both these are datetime data type.

I use the following logic to load delta values:

```
INSERT INTO SINK_TBL 
SELECT * FROM Data_Source_Table WHERE TIMESTAMP_Column > @last_run and TIMESTAMP_Column <= @current_max_date
INSERT INTO watermark(tablename,dt) values ('table_name',@current_max_date)
```

This works fine, but the more I think about this, I am wondering whether there can be a situation where-in while the delta data (above query) is fetched, an insert might occur during that split second and the query may miss that record.

The alternate options I am thinking of are:

1. Subtract 1 second from `@current_max_date`
2. Or change the query to `SELECT * FROM Data_Source_Table WHERE TIMESTAMP_Column >= @last_run and TIMESTAMP_Column < @current_max_date`

What is the safe option to ensure delta load doesn't miss out on any data records.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an absolute guarantee that no records are missed then the best solutions, in theory, would be:

1. Read the DB log files, rather than the tables, to get changes. However this is likely to require a commercial CDC tool if your DBMS doesn't provide a mechanism for doing this
2. Extract the full table each time - though if the data volumes are of any significant size this is unlikely to be practicable/cost-effective

In reality, the best solution is to use the option 1 you listed. How far back you move the start of the window (1 second, 1 minute, 1 hour) depends on how confident you are that your systems are in sync time-wise and what the logic is for writing to TIMESTAMP_Column (i.e. does it get set to sysdate at the point the record is written or is the value being defined at the start of a (potentially long-running) transaction)